# FCM background notification issue android

Tags: android

I am using FCM in my android project and is working fine when app is running. But when the app is killed or closed onReceiveMessage is not called. I have tried by sending message using only data playload also still it is not working. Is there any any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: check this. same i have implemented https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Comment: Is it your code or are you pointing us to an online article you referred to?

Comment: @PravinSonawane He has implemented code using above tutorial.

Comment: @CHIRANJITBARDHAN would be helpful if you share 'your' code. Anyways, the code seems fine. If you are sending a data message like this, you should get a notification even when the app is not in the foreground. `{
  "to": "APA91...zvmu",
  "data": {
    "msgTitle": "New title",
    "message": "You have a notification"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will solve your problem. `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification("", "");
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String xyz, String abc) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();


        b.putString("key", xyz);
        b.putString("key", abc);

    intent.putExtras(b);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("body")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    boolean useSilhouette = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
    if (useSilhouette) {
        try {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_sillate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_sillate);
        }
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    //Random id number for notification
    Random random = new Random();
    int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

    notificationManager.notify(m/* ID of notification */,           notificationBuilder.build());
     }
   }
```

Get values via `getIntent()` in MainActivity and do what you want to do ;)

Comment: i have implemented same way. its not work when app is closed.